# Computing persistent homology Betti numbers on big data

Tags: python, voxel, topology

I have a huge 3D big data (128×128×128). I want to compute the Betti numbers for this 3D data. I tried using the moguTDA and ripser packages from Python and my kernel dies when I try computing the Betti numbers. Is there a big data approach to compute the Betti numbers?

Comment: Can you show the code that's causing your Python kernel to "die". Does it just stop? Is there an exception?

Comment: @DarkKnight, I am using this from gudhi. rips_complex = gudhi.RipsComplex(points=point_cloud, max_edge_length=epsilon). My point cloud in this case is of shape (884736,3). I don't see any exception. I think it is because the data is huge

Comment: To be clear, these are obtained from a 3D voxel. These aren't the raw point cloud data

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are trying to compute. You mention voxel data and Gudhi, so I would have expected gudhi.CubicalComplex, but you seem to derive a point cloud and build its RipsComplex instead?

For a cubical complex, 128³ is far from huge, gudhi.CubicalComplex can handle that easily. For significantly larger input, I recommend reading the recent paper [Slice, Simplify and Stitch: Topology-Preserving Simplification Scheme for Massive Voxel Data](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2023/17910/pdf/LIPIcs-SoCG-2023-60.pdf). It is about the software [Cubicle](https://bitbucket.org/hubwag/cubicle), which was used in particular on grids of size 2048³ (on a laptop). It also mentions other software like [Cubical Ripser](https://github.com/shizuo-kaji/CubicalRipser_3dim) and TTK (topology toolkit).

Rips filtrations are a different business. By default, gudhi.RipsComplex first computes the distance between each pair of points, to check if it is less than max_edge_length. This quadratic behavior is already hard to manage for a million points. In low dimension, it seldom makes sense to use a Rips filtration, gudhi.AlphaComplex makes much more sense.

Note that if other software causes the Python kernel to crash, you could try reporting a bug to the authors of such software, sometimes a small tweak can replace that with an exception.